# Querying non-partition and non-row key in the Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

My table structure has a Partition key, Row key, and a column containing JSON data. I want to query the table based on the partition key and a particular value from the JSON data.

Sample JSON Data:

```
{"ConsumerId":"7","value01":"850.58"}
```

The query I have created is

```
var query = new TableQuery<CloudModelDetail>().Where(TableQuery.CombineFilters(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, retailerReferenceId),
            TableOperators.And, TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("CloudModelJsonData","Contains", consumerId)));
```

But it is not giving me the desired results. Can anyone help me with the correct query?

Comment: If you are already working with json objects you may want to consider Document DB. I believe it should be possible to query in document db by a json property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table Storage doesn't support wildcard matching like `Contains`, unfortunately. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/query-operators-supported-for-the-table-service)

You can consider using `CompareTo`, which can act like `StartsWith`, as an inequality matcher - but this will only work if your JSON data always starts with `{"ConsumerId":"value",`

Better yet - add `ConsumerId` as an additional field, or rethink the partition and row key structure to make use of composite keys that include the consumer ID, which should also help performance.